# Indexed family of all unary partial computable functions

Tags: computability, enumeration

Please help prove the following statement:

> The indexed family of all unary partial computable functions that have total computable extension is computable.

Definitions:

1. Total function - a function which is defined for all inputs of the right type, that is, for all of a domain.
2. A function $g$ is called an extension of the partial function $f$ if $\operatorname{Dom}(f) ⊆ \operatorname{Dom}(g)$ and $g(x) = f(x)$ for any $x \in \operatorname{Dom}(f)$, where $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$ is the domain of the function.
3. Let $S$ be nonempty countable set (possibly finite). Any surjective map $\nu\colon \omega \twoheadrightarrow S$ from the set $\omega$ of natural numbers onto the set $S$ is called an enumeration .
4. An indexed family of functions is called computable if it has at least one computable enumeration.

Additional information:

- The indexed family of all unary computable functions is not computable.

Comment: You haven't specified how the input is represented – presumably as a Turing machine computing the input unary p.c. function.

Comment: I assume that by "continuation" you mean "extension".

Comment: Let $f$ be the unary partial computable function defined as follows: if the $n$'th Turing machine halts after $T$ steps then $f(n) = T$, and $f(n) = \bot$ otherwise. Note that $f$ cannot be extended to a computable function, since that would allow you to solve the halting problem. Now given a Turing machine $M$, let $f_M$ be the function that first runs $M$ on the empty input, and if $M$ halts, forwards execution to $f$. Then $f_M$ is a unary partial computable function, and $f_M$ can be extended to a total computable function iff $M$ doesn't halt on the empty input.

Comment: My comment disproves your statement.

Comment: I'm not good at this subject. I know that a family of functions is called computable if it has at least one computable numbering. I suppose it is necessary to find such a numbering and thereby prove this statement, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: I believe that your statement is false. You won't be able to prove it.

Comment: Can you describe *exactly* which language you are claiming to be computable? I'm not sure what "the family of all unary partial computable functions that have a total computable extension" means, that is, what do elements of this family look like, and what would it mean for such a family to be computable. You mentioned computable numbering, but I'm not sure what this means. I understand Turing machines.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This is not about any language being computable. This is about whether there exists a computable numbering.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to provide the definition.

Comment: It seems that you want to show that your collection is *recursively enumerable* (the usual term). This doesn't really help, since it is known that the set of non-halting Turing machines is not recursively enumerable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The question is not asking whether the set of *all* Turing machines computing such functions is computably enumerable. It is asking whether there is a recursively enumerable set such that a partial computable function has a computable continuation iff it has SOME program in our c.e. set.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of computable partial functions admits a computable numbering if there is a computable function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{F} = \{\varphi_{f(e)} \mid e \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $(\varphi_e)_{e \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a standard enumeration of the computable partial functions.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the collection of computable partial functions whose domain is either $\mathbb{N}$ or some $\{0,\ldots,n\}$.

**Claim**: $\mathcal{I}$ admits a computable numbering.

*Proof*: Let $\iota(n)$ denote the program:

1. Input $k \in \mathbb{N}$
2. For each $0 \leq i < k$ simulate $\phi_n(i)$.
3. Simulate $\varphi_n(k)$ and output its output

Clearly, if $\varphi_n$ is total, then $\varphi_{\iota(n)} = \varphi_n$. Otherwise $\varphi_{\iota(n)}$ is defined in some initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, $\iota$ is a computable numbering of $\mathcal{I}$.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of partial computable functions admit a computable total continuation. It is easy to see that $\mathcal{C}$ is also the class of partial computable function admitting an extension in $\mathcal{I}$. As the domain of a partial computable function is c.e., we can then show:

**Claim**: $\mathcal{C}$ admits a computable numbering.

*Proof*: Let $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ be a standard pairing function. We define $c : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by letting $c(\langle e, n \rangle)$ be the program:

1. Input $k \in \mathbb{N}$
2. Simulate $\varphi_n(k)$
3. Simulate $\varphi_{\iota(e)}(k)$ and output its result.

Now $c$ is a computable numbering for $\mathcal{C}$. To see this, we first note that $\varphi_{c(\langle e,n\rangle)}$ is the restriction of $\varphi_{\iota(e)}$ to the set $\operatorname{dom}(\varphi_n)$. This establishes  $\varphi_{c(\langle e,n\rangle)} \in \mathcal{C}$ for any $e, n$. Conversely, assume that $f$ is a partial computable function with a total computable continuation $g$. Let $f = \varphi_n$ and $g = \varphi_e$. Then $f = \varphi_{c(\langle e, n\rangle)}$, so we do get indeed each member of $\mathcal{C}$ in the range of $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you explain in more details the part of the proof in the case of the collection  _C_. I don't fully understand why _c_ can be considered the computable numbering for _C_

Comment: @TuS I've added the proof why $c$ is a computable numbering of $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Is there another form of the definition of  _ι(n)_  and  _c(⟨e,n⟩)_ ? I haven't seen a recording form using a program before. I want to be sure that I understand everything correctly

Comment: You can read "be the program" as "be a G\"odel number for the Turing machine that essentially does the following", if you are more comfortable with that. But in terms of conceptual simplicity, this is what you get.

Comment: One more question. Is the term "collection" equivalent to indexed family?

Comment: As I understand term "computable partial functions" is not equivalent to term "partial computable functions"?

Comment: c.e. means Computable Enumeration or something else?

Comment: By the term of the "standard pairing function", do you mean the Cantor function?

Comment: @TuS Speaking of indexed family here is incorrect, as no indexing has been fixed yet. I am taking about the standard notion of computable partial functions here, where the computation has to diverge outside of the domain. ce means computably enumerable. A standard pairing function is any computable isomorphism between $\mathbb{N] \times \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I received an answer that such an assignment of the functions phi does not correspond to what is claimed. Do you have any other ideas how to prove this statement?